# react-native run-ios just generates a whole bunch of errors - how to debug

Tags: react-native

I decided to start over on a new react-native project so I updated my react-client to the latest 2.0, updated cocoapods to latest version, and I just initialized a blank react-native project, yarn added a bunch of dependencies, react-native linked with no errors and then tried to run and got a whole bunch of errors.  Did I miss something very obvious?

Steps:

```
react-native init Foo && cd Foo
yarn add react-dom 
yarn add react-apollo
yarn add @shoutem/ui 
yarn add apollo-client@^0.6.0 
yarn add react-dom redux 
yarn add react-redux 
yarn add redux-thunk 
yarn add bluebird 
yarn add redux-actions 
yarn add react-native-lock 
yarn add redux-persist
react-native link
react-native run-ios
```

Errors:

```
=== BUILD TARGET RNVectorIcons OF PROJECT RNVectorIcons WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===


Check dependencies



CompileC /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.o RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/mycomputer/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-darwin-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin:/Users/mycomputer/.dnx/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Applications/sdk/platform-tools:/Applications/sdk/tools:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fbuild-session-file=/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/ModuleCache/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-infinite-recursion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -iquote /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/RNVectorIcons-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/RNVectorIcons-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/RNVectorIcons-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/RNVectorIcons-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/../../React -I../react-native/React -I../react-native/React/Base -I../react-native/React/CSSLayout -I../react-native/React/Executors -I../react-native/React/Modules -I../react-native/React/Profiler -I../react-native/React/Views -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/node_modules/react-native/React -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.dia -c /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m -o /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.o

In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:40:28: error: redefinition of 'RCTLogLevel'
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogLevel) {
                           ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:40:28: note: previous definition is here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogLevel) {
                           ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:41:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogLevelTrace'
  RCTLogLevelTrace = 0,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:41:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogLevelTrace = 0,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:42:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogLevelInfo'
  RCTLogLevelInfo = 1,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:42:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogLevelInfo = 1,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:43:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogLevelWarning'
  RCTLogLevelWarning = 2,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:43:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogLevelWarning = 2,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:44:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogLevelError'
  RCTLogLevelError = 3,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:44:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogLevelError = 3,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:45:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogLevelFatal'
  RCTLogLevelFatal = 4
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:45:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogLevelFatal = 4
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:51:28: error: redefinition of 'RCTLogSource'
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogSource) {
                           ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:51:28: note: previous definition is here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, RCTLogSource) {
                           ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:52:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogSourceNative'
  RCTLogSourceNative = 1,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:52:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogSourceNative = 1,
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:10:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTConvert.h:17:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTLog.h:53:3: error: redefinition of enumerator 'RCTLogSourceJavaScript'
  RCTLogSourceJavaScript = 2
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:10:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTLog.h:53:3: note: previous definition is here
  RCTLogSourceJavaScript = 2
  ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:11:
In file included from ../react-native/React/Base/RCTBridge.h:13:
/Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTBridgeModule.h:55:11: warning: duplicate protocol definition of 'RCTBridgeModule' is ignored
@protocol RCTBridgeModule <NSObject>
          ^
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m:9:
In file included from /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.h:9:
../react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:55:11: note: previous definition is here
@protocol RCTBridgeModule <NSObject>
          ^
1 warning and 9 errors generated.



** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

    CompileC /Users/mycomputer/Projects/Foo/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/RNVectorIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RNVectorIconsManager.o RNVectorIconsManager/RNVectorIconsManager.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Foo.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running React Native 0.40 (run `react-native --version`), you will need to install the latest 'react-native-vector-icons' due to [breaking change for iOS native headers](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0).

In the 'shoutem/ui' package.json, the latest version will not be installed because of the semver definition (^2.0.3 which will only install up to v2.1.0).

Try do the following to solve the issue:

1. Uninstall react-native-vector-icons with `yarn remove react-native-vector-icons`.
2. Re-install it with `yarn add react-native-vector-icons`.
3. Run `react-native link` to link back the lib dependencies to Xcode project.

You might have similar issue with other libraries too if they rely on the iOS native headers. Hopefully, they would have release a new version to address this issue. (The fix is to update the header import declaration e.g. from `#import "RCTUtils.h"` to `#import <React/RCTUtils.h>`)

P.S: If you are not urgently in need of RN 0.40, try initialize your project with pre v0.40 by running `react-native init yourProjectName --version 0.39.2` which would allow you to continue working without waiting for the respective library to fix it.